# get particular json value http post android studio

Tags: java, android, json, http-post

I am a beginner in android development. I have upload the file, and get the response from server. However, the response contains the value that I dont want. 
The server response as: Value {"time_used":53840,"result_idcard":{"index1":0,"index2":0,"confidence":87.42464,"}}.

I only want the confidence level only. How I can extract that? When I run the code below, the logcat shows:

Error: org.json.JSONException  of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray.

Please help me..

/**
     * Uploading the file to server
     */

```
private class UploadFileToServer extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> {
    String docPath= null;
    String facePath=null;

    public UploadFileToServer(String docPath, String facePath) throws JSONException {
        this.docPath = docPath;
        this.facePath = facePath;

            }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        // setting progress bar to zero
        progressBar.setProgress(0);
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        // Making progress bar visible
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        // updating progress bar value
        progressBar.setProgress(progress[0]);

        // updating percentage value
        txtPercentage.setText(String.valueOf(progress[0]) + "%");


        //code to show progress in notification bar
        FileUploadNotification fileUploadNotification = new FileUploadNotification(UploadActivity.this);
        fileUploadNotification.updateNotification(String.valueOf(progress[0]), "Image 123.jpg", "Camera Upload");


    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return uploadFile();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public String uploadFile() {

        String responseString = null;

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Config.FILE_UPLOAD_URL);

        try {
            AndroidMultiPartEntity entity = new AndroidMultiPartEntity(
                    new ProgressListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void transferred(long num) {
                            publishProgress((int) ((num / (float) totalSize) * 100));
                        }
                    });


            entity.addPart("imageIdCard", new FileBody(new File(docPath)));
            entity.addPart("imageBest", new FileBody(new File(facePath)));


            totalSize = entity.getContentLength();
            httppost.setEntity(entity);


            // Making server call
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity r_entity = response.getEntity();

            int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                // Server response

                responseString = EntityUtils.toString(r_entity);

            } else {
                responseString = "Error occurred! Http Status Code: "
                        + statusCode;
            }

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            responseString = e.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            responseString = e.toString();
        }

        return responseString;
    }

                @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        //super.onPostExecute(result);

        //if (result != null)

                    try
                    {
                        //Convert response string to Json Array
                        JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(result);

                        //Iterate through and retrieve club fields
                        int n = ja.length();
                        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

                            //Get individual Json object from Json Array
                            JSONObject jo = ja.getJSONObject(i);

                            //Retrieve each Json object's fields
                            String request_id = jo.getString("request_id");
                            Double confidence = jo.getDouble("confidence");

                            //float confidence= BigDecimal.valueOf(jo.getDouble("result_idcard/confidence")).floatValue();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e("JSONException", "Error: " + e.toString());
                    }
                    //Log.e(TAG, "Response from server: " + result);

                    // showing the server response in an alert dialog
                    showAlert(result);
                }
}
```

[this is the response from server before making the changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpPDR.jpg)

Comment: The JSON string you have provided is not valid JSON. There is a comma behind the value `"confidence":87.42464,"`  (behind the last "4")! Please proved sufficient and accurate information when you ask a Question. We take your Question seriously and so should you.

Comment: the response of server is actually have , at the end.. the server is from vendor. I only use API key..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're converting the JSON result to `JSONArray` but the result is just an object. So directly parse it to object and get the nodes you need. And also, the `result_idcard` is object, you also need to convert it to `JSONObject` then get the `confidence` node.

Try this:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
     try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);

        //Retrieve each Json object's fields
        JSONObject request_id = jsonObject.getJSONObject("result_idcard");
        Double confidence = request_id.getDouble("confidence");

        showAlert(confidence);
     } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
}
```

Comment: the response from server is still same as previous. it still display all value instead of only confidence value.

Comment: I fixed your error on `JSONException`, if you want to modify the repsonse of the server, you must do it to the server itself. The thing you can only do on android is to parse the whole response and get the specific fields you want.

Comment: Sorry for dumb question. but is any way to  neglect these information and only focus on confidence values.? As i want the user see only that confidence value..

Comment: As for my answer, I'd only parsed/get the `confidence` value.

Comment: What is your suggestion to display the confidence value only?

Comment: I've updated my code to `showAlert()` only the `confidence` value.

Comment: * Method to show alert dialog
   */
  private void showAlert(String message) {
   AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
   builder.setMessage(message).setTitle("Response from Servers")
     .setCancelable(false)
     .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
       // do nothing
      }
     });
   AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
   alert.show();
  }

Comment: Well yes, because you want to display ONLY the confidence value. I told you that if you want to have the confidence value only from the response of the server, you need to modify it to the server itself. Please test and clarify what do you actually want to do.

Comment: I dont have priviledges to edit at the server because I only use the API key to access the server. The server is from the vendor.

Comment: Yes that's it. This code will get what you want, the `confidence` value.

Comment: I try your code and the logcat said that : org.json.JSONException: No value for confidence. I have edit my code as above.

Comment: It works for me, I just remove the last comma on the confidence value (according to sir Barns). Maybe the response is not like that? Please double check it.

Comment: @NurhannanKhairi  :: if the code you just edited is the code you are using and you get the error you just stated--That is because you did not follow Trenten's solution. For the basic scheme of your JSON string (please see what I wrote earlier: your JSON you have posted is not valid!) I see no reason why Tenten's solution should not work. NurhannanKhairi  Please review you work and please work diligently.

Comment: is this line showAlert(String.valueOf(confidence)); correct? and I dont need to change anything at the show alert method right? what do you mean by remove the last comma on the confidence value? I dont understand.. Sorry for my bad in english.

Comment: As you can see here: `"confidence":87.42464,"`, there's a comma (,) at the last part of the value, 87.42464. It makes the JSON invalid. Is this actually what you're getting from the server? Can you provide the screenshot of the response from the server?

Comment: @Barns, Thank you sir. Just passing time, helping gives satisfaction to me specially when it works. hehe. (sorry for the off-topic comment)

Comment: yes. I follow what Tenten said as in code that I edited above. I upload to server, and the logcat said: org.json.JSONException: No value for confidence. and it indicate two lines which are :  Double confidence = jsonObject.getDouble("confidence"); and  private class UploadFileToServer extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> {

Comment: It seems that the response doesn't contain any `confidence.` As per sir Barns said, please review your work, check the response if it actually contains `confidence` node. Double check everything, and update us with what you've found.

Comment: Tenten, how can I inbox you? so I can give the screenshot of the output..

Comment: Tenten, I add the image of screenshot of response server at the above post before the changes is made.

Comment: I can't barely see it xD I don't know if the `result_idcard` is object or array.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the OP's question (so far) and the (invalid) JSON example the OP provided I have hacked out a little test for them to try. Perhaps the OP will get the idea of how this works.

Just put this code somewhere in you activity and call `startJsonTest();`. You will see the response in the logcat.

```
private void startJsonTest(){
    // The JSON the OP provide in their question!
    String json = "{'time_use':53840,'result_idcard':{'index1':0,'index2':0,'confidence':87.42464}}";
    testYourJson(json);
}

private void testYourJson(String result) {
    try {
        if(result == null || result.isEmpty()){
            Log.e("testYourJson", "Something went wrong!");
            return;
        }

        Log.e("testYourJson", result);

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
        //Retrieve each Json object's fields
        int time = jsonObject.optInt("time_use", -1);
        Log.e("testYourJson", "time = " + time);
        JSONObject request_id = jsonObject.getJSONObject("result_idcard");

        Double confidence = request_id.optDouble("confidence", -222.0f);
        int index1 = request_id.optInt("index1", -1);
        int index2 = request_id.optInt("index2", -1);

        // Show a little confidence ;-)
        Log.e("testYourJson", "confidence  = " + confidence);
        Log.e("testYourJson", "index1  = " + index1);
        Log.e("testYourJson", "index2  = " + index2);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("testYourJson", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

The only difference to **Tenten's solution** (which is correct) is that I have used `optInt` and `optDouble` because you can substitute optional values.

This works! I have tested it. But I suspect that the JSON you have is different to what you provide.
Good Luck!

**EDIT** 
After taking a good long HARD look at the screen shot the OP has linked to his Question it appears as if `index1` and `index2` are actually `Double` values! so the actual working code would need to compensate for that!

Comment: Mr Barns, am i need to take care the index 1 and index 2 also? as I only want to display the confidence value..

Comment: No. I was just giving an example of how to parse those values if you need them in the future, and how to parse `integer` values. Take what you want and ignore the rest. This is just a test method so you can see how it would work (if the JSON you actual have is like the one you posted).

Comment: Thank you so much Mr barns. I got the expected result.:)